# Как расположить текст на одном уровне с картинкой

Tags: html, css

Как расположить текст на одном уровне с картинкой как на 2 скриншоте?

HTML:

```
  <img src="img/cart.png" class="cart" alt="">
  <div class="block2">
    <h1 class="block2">Для кого это нужно?</h1>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.cart {
    height: auto;
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin-left: 25%;
    padding-top: 4%;
    line-height: 1.25;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

h1.block2 {
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Сейчас:

[image: Сейчас]

Нужно:

[image: Необходимый результат]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вложить в таблицу:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGGmA.png" height=150px;>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Для кого это необходимо?</h2>
            <div class="radiogroup" display="block-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Розничная торговля<br>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Интернет торговля<br>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Кафе и ресторан<br>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Сфера услуг
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```